# Geoserver - PostGIS performance issue

Tags: performance, postgresql, jdbc, postgis, geoserver

We have noticed something strange in the interaction between our Geoserver instance and Postgres/PostGIS.

After setting Geoserver's log level to include developer debugging, I managed to capture a single request from Geoserver WMS to PostGIS.

The (shortened) sequence of events and their timestamps:

```
12:31:22,658 - SELECT query for MSG is sent to Postgres
12:32:10,315 - Rendering for MSG layer starts
12:32:10,356 - DB Connection Closed
~ 48 seconds
```

Interestingly enough, when I execute the same query (MSG) directly from PgAdmin3:

```
SELECT "frp_mw",encode(ST_AsBinary(ST_Force_2D("the_geom")),'base64') as "the_geom" FROM "public"."af_msg_abba_datetime_today" WHERE ("the_geom" && GeometryFromText('POLYGON ((-27.67968749408379 -46.92207325648429, -27.67968749408379 -6.186892358058866, 75.67968748740275 -6.186892358058866, 75.67968748740275 -46.92207325648429, -27.67968749408379 -46.92207325648429))', 4326) AND (("frp_mw" >= -1 AND "frp_mw" <= 150) OR ("frp_mw" >= 151 AND "frp_mw" <= 300) OR ("frp_mw" >= 301 AND "frp_mw" <= 600) OR ("frp_mw" >= 601 AND "frp_mw" <= 50000)));
```

I get 6515 rows in 380 ms.

Ie Postgres is able to return the results of the query within 380ms if queried from PgAdmin3 but Geoserver takes about 48 seconds to get hold of the same resultset.

Is this some kind of JDBC problem perhaps?

Some details about our setup:

Master Postgres database is on a separate VM from Geoserver, but we replicate to a slave Postgres cluster on the Geoserver VM (same host). So Geoserver is referencing the 'localhost' read-only Postgres cluster for its queries.

The 380 ms response time shown above was from the slave Postgres cluster, same one that Geoserver is using.

All Linux (Ubuntu 11.10) based. Postgres 9.1 PostGIS 1.5 Geoserver 2.1.3

Comment: Do you get all 6k rows in pgadmin downloaded to the client, or only the first 100?

Comment: I executed the query in a separate Query window and I think then it returns all the rows to the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GeoServer fetches data in blocks of 1000, renders them, fetches the next block, and so on, to avoid having a big memory footprint in case of many concurrent requests. So the 48s is not the time to load the data, but to load and render it.
Loading data in a single shot is faster, but there is no way to control the memory footprint.

Moreover, are you using prepared statements in the data store configuration?

Comment: From the log it looked like the rendering only started after about 48s.

    2012-07-20 12:32:10,315 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - trying to render symbol circle
    2012-07-20 12:32:10,315 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - rendering mark @ PointRenderer circle
    2012-07-20 12:32:10,316 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - fetching mark of name circle
    2012-07-20 12:32:10,316 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - returning circle

Comment: Prepared statements are enabled and maximum open set to 50.

Comment: Ah, switching off prepared statements solved my problem! Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Fun fact: while the data source settings in our GeoServer 2.6.2 shows "fetch size: 1000", the actual query shows "LIMIT 1000000".

Comment: @arjan you're mistaking JDBC driver paging (which you cannot see from the query, it's a setting of how query results are trasferred from dbms to client) from the total amount of data returned from the query.